# How do I avoid security warnings in IE8 when using Google Maps on https

Tags: javascript, google-maps, security-warning

I use Google Maps on my project through https, but it will cause this problem above, other browsers will work fine. I have searched it for a long time, but no solution, someone said that this problem caused by using free Google Maps key (according to [Google's FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#ssl)).

I am not sure for it.

the main code are as below:

```
<script id="mapLink1" type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false&region=hk&language=<%= MapLanguage %>"></script>
<script id="mapLink2" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js"></script>
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that any marker images are loaded with a HTTPS URL?

Darren